# replace path with jquery.address

Tags: jquery, deep-linking

I'm implementing global navigation on my web site, which I going to make deep linkable.

Navigation bar is presented in all pages. Each link in this navigation has following format

> /categories/id

I' have a standard code, provided from [oficial example](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/).

When I'm on an index page and clicking navigation links, deeplinking works well – url is replaced from "http://example.com" to, say

> http://example.com/categories/39

The problem occurs, when I first load page with url "http://example.com/categories/39".

When I clicking some of the links on navigation, url gets duplicated like this:

> http://example.com/categories/39/categories/42

How can a fix this issue?

Thanks!

**Update**

I found, that this is possible with native JavaScript API:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/zzz")
```

but, how to do it with jquery.address…?

Comment: `I' have a standard code, provided from oficial example.` a link to that *official* would be nice, also make sure to add some code in your Q if you want some help, otherwise it's hard to guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I should provide "/" to $jquery.address.init() method:

```
$.address.state("/").init(...
```

instead of:

```
&.address.state(document.location.pathname).init(...
```